# How to set a background then create rounded corners using GD or ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

The problem I have is quite simple, I'm hoping somebody with GD or ImageMagick experience can answer it.

I have a source `.gif` (which may or may not have transparency).  I want to set a background (a gradient, though specifics shouldn't matter), put the `.gif` on top of that, then round the corners.  The rounded corner areas should be transparent.  Note that if the `.gif` is *not* transparent, the background would have no effect, since the `.gif` would go on top of it.  This is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a mask, check [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/channels/#masks) for examples.